# r how to subset without retaining all data info from original set?

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to subset data.

here's the link to sample data to play around with:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwIbultIWxeVOFdRaE81Nm9qc2s/view?usp=sharing

so in this data set, the last column has name `"Type"`, which has 2 values: `"normal."` and `"back."`
and let's say i am subsetting based on the `"Type"` column:

```
test.data = read.csv(file = paste0(dd, '/data_example.csv'))
test.subdata1 = subset(test.data, test.data$Type == 'normal.')
test.subdata2 = test.data[test.data$Type == 'normal.',]
```

here, I'm subsetting using two most common methods:

1. by using `subset()`
2. by directly filtering in the `[]`

supposedly, the new subsetted data should only contain data that has ``` Type ``"normal." ``` (there's a period behind the word)
and indeed, when i view the subset data table, there's only `"normal."` ones present.

HOWEVER, the thing is, the `"back."` class info is retained in my subsetted data, as shown in following output:

```
str(test.subdata1$Type)
# Factor w/ 2 levels "back.","normal.": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
str(test.subdata2$Type)
# Factor w/ 2 levels "back.","normal.": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

so it does not matter which subsetting method i use, the complete information from the original data set will be retained in my subset data set.

**my question is:**
HOW to get rid of the extra info from the original data set i do not want to retain in my subset data set?

meaning, how can i see only 1 factor level in my subset data and not 2 factor levels?

Comment: Please don't post links to data.  Use the output of `dput()`.

Comment: @BryanHanson thank you so much! i could not find that post because i was not using the right keywords... thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
# Is this what you need?
test.subdata1$Type = as.factor(as.integer(test.subdata1$Type))

# or maybe
test.subdata1$Type = factor(test.subdata1$Type)
```

Comment: Thank you Rick! That is actually exactly what i need :)